# Iterator over elements around specific index in Vec<Vec<Object>>

Tags: rust

I have a grid: `Vec<Vec<Object>>` and a pair of x/y indices. I want to find all the elements *surrounding* the one indexed.

Unfortunately, I can't simply loop over the elements because that ends up borrowing the `Vec` twice and the borrow checker screams at me:

```
let mut cells = Vec::with_capacity(8);

for cx in xstart..xend {
    for cy in ystart..yend {
        if cx != x || cy != y {
            cells.push(&mut squares[cy as usize][cx as usize]);
        }
    }
}

cells.into_iter()
```

My best attempt at changing this into an iterator chain has also failed spectacularly:

```
let xstart = if x == 0 { x } else { x - 1 };
let xlen = if x + 2 > squares[0].len() { x + 1 } else { 3 };
let ystart = if y == 0 { y } else { y - 1 };
let ylen = if y + 2 > squares.len() { y + 1 } else { 3 };

let xrel = x - xstart;
let yrel = y - ystart;

squares.iter().enumerate()
    .skip(ystart).take(ylen).flat_map(|(i, ref row)|
        row.iter().enumerate()
            .skip(xstart).take(xlen).filter(|&(j, &c)| i != yrel || j != xrel))
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, are you working on Conway's Game of Life?

Comment: Nope, minesweeper :)

Comment: You should update your example to be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it is right now, we don't have values or types for many of the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I made a custom iterator with the help of the guys in `#rust`

I've `type`d my struct out to give you the actual code. As pointed out by the guys in `#rust` you cannot return `&mut` safely from an iterator without using a different iterator that uses `unsafe` anyway, and given that the math here is simple enough to ensure it doesn't go wrong an unsafe was the way to go.

```rust
type FieldSquare = u8;

use std::iter::Iterator;

pub struct SurroundingSquaresIter<'a> {
    squares: &'a mut Vec<Vec<FieldSquare>>,
    center_x: usize,
    center_y: usize,
    current_x: usize,
    current_y: usize,
}

pub trait HasSurroundedSquares<'a> {
    fn surrounding_squares(&'a mut self, x: usize, y:usize) -> SurroundingSquaresIter<'a>;
}

impl<'a> HasSurroundedSquares<'a> for Vec<Vec<FieldSquare>> {
    fn surrounding_squares(&'a mut self, x: usize, y:usize) -> SurroundingSquaresIter<'a> {
        SurroundingSquaresIter {
            squares: self,
            center_x: x,
            center_y: y,
            current_x: if x == 0 { x } else { x - 1 },
            current_y: if y == 0 { y } else { y - 1 },
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for SurroundingSquaresIter<'a> {
    type Item = &'a mut FieldSquare;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a mut FieldSquare> {
        if self.current_y + 1 > self.squares.len() || self.current_y > self.center_y + 1 {
            return None;
        }

        let ret_x = self.current_x;
        let ret_y = self.current_y;

        if self.current_x < self.center_x + 1 && self.current_x + 1 < self.squares[self.current_y].len() {
            self.current_x += 1;
        }
        else {
            self.current_x = if self.center_x == 0 { self.center_x } else { self.center_x - 1 };
            self.current_y += 1;
        }

        if ret_x == self.center_x && ret_y == self.center_y {
            return self.next();
        }

        Some(unsafe { &mut *(&mut self.squares[ret_y][ret_x] as *mut _) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I am not sure I would be comfortable working with an iterator when the relative positions of the elements can be important. Instead, I would seek to create a "view" of those elements.

The [gist can be found here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=998b550ed7a589b1721e&version=stable), but the idea is simple so here are the core structures.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct NeighbourhoodRow<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    pub left    : Option<&'a mut T>,
    pub center  : Option<&'a mut T>,
    pub right   : Option<&'a mut T>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Neighbourhood<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    pub top     : NeighbourhoodRow<'a, T>,
    pub center  : NeighbourhoodRow<'a, T>,
    pub bottom  : NeighbourhoodRow<'a, T>,
}
```

To build them, I use a healthy dose of `split_at_mut`:

```rust
fn take_centered_trio<'a, T>(row: &'a mut [T], x: usize) ->
    (Option<&'a mut T>, Option<&'a mut T>, Option<&'a mut T>)
{
    fn extract<'a, T>(row: &'a mut [T], x: usize) -> (Option<&'a mut T>, &'a mut [T]) {
        if x+1 > row.len() {
            (None, row)
        } else {
            let (h, t) = row.split_at_mut(x+1);
            (Some(&mut h[x]), t)
        }
    }

    let (prev, row) = if x > 0 { extract(row, x-1) } else { (None, row) };
    let (elem, row) = extract(row, 0);
    let (next,  _ ) = extract(row, 0);

    (prev, elem, next)
}
```

and the rest is just some uninteresting constructors.

Of course, you can then build some kind of iterator over *those*.

Comment: Interesting, there is no way to implement a `get_mut` method for `IterMut` that accepts negative integers, thus turning `IterMut` itself into a view, because `IterMut` has no starting pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to get mutable references to all surrounding elements, right? I don't think this is possible to do it directly. The problem is, Rust cannot statically prove that you want mutable references to *different* cells. If it ignored this, then, for example, you could make a slight mistake in indexing and get two mutable references to the same data, which is something Rust guarantees to prevent. Hence it disallows this.

On the language level this is caused by [`IndexMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html) trait. You can see how its only method's `self` parameter lifetime is tied to the result lifetime:

```rust
fn index_mut(&'a mut self, index: Idx) -> &'a mut Self::Output;
```

This means that if this method is called (implicitly through an indexing operation) then the *whole* object will be borrowed mutably until the resulting reference goes out of scope. This prevents calling `&mut a[i]` multiple times.

The most simple and safest way to fix this would be to refactor your code in a "double buffering" manner - you have two instances of the field and copy data between each other on the each step. Alternatively, you can create a temporary field on each step and replace the main one with it after all computations but it is probably less efficient than swapping two fields.

Another way to solve this would be, naturally, using raw `*mut` pointers. This is `unsafe` and should only be used directly as the last resort. You can use unsafety, however, to implement a safe abstraction, something like

```rust
fn index_multiple_mut<'a, T>(input: &'a mut [Vec<T>], indices: &[(usize, usize)]) -> Vec<&'a mut T>
```

where you first check that all indices are different and then use `unsafe` with some pointer casts (with [`transmute`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html), probably) to create the resulting vector.

A third possible way would be to use [`split_at_mut()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) method in some clever way, but I'm not that sure that it is possible, and if it is, it is likely not very convenient.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to do this with iterators? My idea was to make an iterator chain that would do it, but I could write a custom iterator if that's not possible.